# How do I remove Lubuntu and Keep my files?

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu

I run Lubuntu 13.10 on A **S10 Lenovo Ideapad netbook**. I recently installed  Xubuntu using `sudo apt-get instal xubuntu-desktop` .

I want to install Xubuntu ana remove Lubuntu but keep my files .

Any help ?

Comment: You should had some information like: which partitions you currently have, and in which partition the data you want to save is stored!

Comment: Did you do a complete install of Xubuntu or just installed xfce Desktop Environment within the current install? These two are very different choices and will have different implications. **Please edit your original question above** to clarify.

Comment: I installed xubuntu using sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have originally installed Lubuntu and installed Xubuntu in addition, so you now have both of them installed and can choose one from them at the login screen. If you want to get rid off Lubuntu, `apt-get remove lubuntu-desktop` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm understanding it, OP has one partition with Lubuntu on it, and one partition with Xubuntu on it. When OP boots computer, OP chooses between Lubuntu and Xubunutu.

If that is correct, then you want to boot into Xubuntu, and then mount the Lubuntu partition as if though it were, say, an external harddrive. You should be able to see all the files on it. Navigate to your home directory in the Lubuntu partition, select the files that you want to keep, and drag them into your Xubuntu home directory. You have now copied files from Lubuntu to Xubuntu.

As for actually getting rid of the Lubuntu partition, that is a little more complex and potentially dangerous. Do not attempt this without backing up all your data first.c